# Display won't wake from mouse/keyboard input

Tags: 16.04

Everytime my laptop display turns off it refuses to turn back on again with standard keyboard or mouse presses/movements. However, pressing Ctrl-F1 allows me to switch to a console from which I can switch back to the GUI by pressing Ctrl-F7. But, pressing Ctrl-F7 without pressing Ctrl-F1 won't wake it.

This is starting to annoy me and I'd like to fix it - does anybody have any pointers on where to start? I'm guessing this is a configuration problem with X or with NVidia.

For the record, I haven't done anything funny with the drivers or with X. Its been like this since I installed, and after reinstalling (for different reasons) the problem persisted.

Comment: Have you tried pressing the power button? I don't mean holding it down for 10 seconds.

Comment: No, unfortunately that doesn't work - I did try that.